# Reordering the columns in HTML Table

Tags: html

I currently use Coda for all of my HTML editing, and I am working on a part of our site that uses tables. I made a table that is about 12x10, and my boss wants it reordered. Is there any tool available that can make reordering columns a bit less painful?

Comment: I think Dreamweaver is the best tool, use the design view :)

Comment: That may be my backup solution if nothing else comes up, download the trial and reorder my tables.

Answer (score 0):

Use Dreamweaver, you can format your table very easy or you can search any table generator on google.